# Usual continuity in $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't enough, is it possible to define a concept of continuity for rationals that works 'nicely'?

Tags: real-analysis

For example if one considers the usual epsilon-delta definition of continuity then one may prove that functions such as $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ with $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1 & x^2<2 \\
1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ are "continuous" even though if one draws the graph of such a function then one clearly sees big "discontinuities".

Now my question is: Can one make a stronger notion of continuity on the rationals where such pathological behaviors don't arise? If not why and why is the supremum property so important for that matter? (Also does that mean that all sets where the supremum property doesn't arise will have the same problems?)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but uniform continuity springs to mind. Uniformly continuous functions map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, and when defined on $\Bbb{Q}$, can be extended to a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: locally uniform continuity

Comment: It's not clear to me why you feel that function doesn't  deserve to be called continuous. The discontinuitites you think you see aren't really there if  you (somehow) draw a more accurate picture: The function appears to be discontinuous at $\sqrt 2$, but if you could somehow draw an accurate picture of the rationals you wouldn't see a discontinuity at $\sqrt 2$, because there would simply not be any such point as $\sqrt 2$...

Comment: @reuns The given $f$ is locally uniformly continuous; every point in $\Bbb{Q}$ lies in a neighbourhood on which $f$ is constant, and hence uniformly continuous.

Comment: @TheoBendit Right I was thinking to uniform on every compact / bounded interval, for non-complete space it is not the same as uniform on some open around every point

Comment: To further agree with @DavidC.Ullrich, insisting on the existence on some larger space is, if anything, a bit arbitrary. We could behold the continuous function $\cos(x)$ on $\mathbb{R},$ and we could think of $\mathbb{R}$ as the circle with a point removed. The function doesn't extend continuously to the bigger space (there is no limit as $x$ tends to $\infty$), but as nice a continuous function as you can imagine.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I wouldn't consider it arbitrary. Every metric space can be embedded densely in a unique (up to surjective isometry) complete metric space. In that sense, if you have an incomplete space like $\Bbb{Q}$ lying in a complete space like $\Bbb{R}$ (or even larger ones like $\Bbb{R}^2$), the capacity for a function to be extended continuously to the larger space is actually an intrinsic property of the function lying in the smaller space. This property is stronger than continuity.

Comment: That all depends on the point of view that your metric isn't, to some extent arbitrary. I mean... the arctan metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to the usual metric, but the latter isn't complete, since it can see $-\infty$ and $\infty$, but the two agree on what constitutes a continuous function. What you're saying is, of course, completely correct, I'm just saying that the fact that you can check the extension in the small space doesn't, to me, imply that it is, per se, natural.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Not just small space, the unique, smallest complete space containing the original space. In a topological space, sure, there is no such notion. However, the asker specifically mentioned the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, and tagged the question real-analysis; I think that assuming at least a metric is not out of order here. Looking at $\Bbb{Q}$ as a metric space (or indeed, as a uniform space), there is a "natural" strengthening of the concept of continuity in the way that the asker wants there to be.